# jquery removal of a <li> is not removing the node from the list

Tags: jquery, html-lists, element

I am having an issue where a list item is not being removed as expected from my list after the user clicks on a button from a popup.

```
$('#srsDetail_btnRemovePerson').off().on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#srsDetail_Users .ui-selected").each(function (i, o) {
            if (app.showConfirmModalFunc(mg.ConfirmDeleteRecord, 'Delete User', function () {   $(o).remove(); }))  {
                return;
            }
        });
    });
```

Below is the image prior to deletion.
[image]

Now is the picture after deletion.
[image]

I don't want the orange row to be there anymore as it should only have 2 rows after the deletion.  This row needs to be removed because it is used to remove the backend data.

Any ideas on how to remove the list item only?

Below is the css:

```
.simpleselectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
.simpleselectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
.simpleselectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 97%;  }
.simpleselectable li { margin: 3px; padding: 0.4em; font-size: 0.8em; height: 30px; line-height: 1em; border:solid 1px #DDD; background-color:#CCE5ED; cursor:pointer; margin-left: 3px;}
   .simpleselectable li:focus { background: green;    }
```

picture of the html used
[image]

Comment: In the normal case, that orange area wouldn't be there. We'll need to see more of your markup and CSS. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: you need to show your HTML code also ... my Guess is that some HTML code is still in there ... you will get that if you can inspect element and check